# EM algorithm for normal mixtures with constraints

Tags: r, machine-learning, expectation-maximization, latent-variable, heterogeneity

I have $G$ groups, each with $N_g$ data points $y_{ig}$, $g=1,\dots,G$ and $i = 1, \dots, N_g$. The group for each data point in observable.

I want to estimate the normal mixtures model with $K$ unobservable types, assuming that the type proportions $q_{kg}, k = 1,\dots, K$ are common across groups; i.e. for each $k$ I assume $$q_{k1} = q_{k2} = \dots = q_{kG} = q_k, \quad \text{where} \quad \sum_k q_k = 1. \tag1$$

In other words, I assume a data point $y_{ig}$ is drawn from a normal distribution $\Phi(\cdot; \mu_{kg}, \sigma_{kg})$ with probability $q_{kg} = q_k$. The problem is, how to estimate the parameters $\mu_{kg}, \sigma_{kg}$ and $q_{k}$.

By using expectation-maximization algorithm, I could easily estimate the model separately for each group, but the type proportions $q_{kg}$ would then not agree across different groups. Thus, I need to implement the constraint (1) in the estimation procedure. The question is, how to do it in the context of the EM algorithm?

I use R for the numerics, although as a first step a mathematical explanation suffices.

**Edit: an example**

Here is an example I have tried to solve: First, I simulate the data, and then I try to estimate it by using the EM algorithm, but something goes wrong, and I am not able to reproduce all the parameters from the simulated data set.

I assume I observe each individual's group $g \in \{1,2\}$ together with three iid data points $y_{it} \sim \Phi(\cdot; \mu_{kg}, \sigma_{kg}), t \in \{1,2,3\},$ for each individual. Here $k \in \{1,2,3\}$ is the unobservable latent type of the individual.

```
require(data.table)

lognormpdf <- function(Y,mu=0,sigma=1)  {
  -0.5 * (  (Y-mu) / sigma )^2   - 0.5 * log(2.0*pi) - log(sigma)  
}

logsumexp <- function(v) {
  vm = max(v)
  log(sum(exp(v-vm))) + vm
}

logrowSumexp <- function(v) {
  vm = max(v)
  log(rowSums(exp(v-vm))) + vm
}

model.fun <-function(nk) {
  
  model = list()
  # model for Y1,Y2,Y3|k 
  model$A     = array(3*(1 + 3*runif(3*nk)),c(nk))
  model$S     = array(1,c(nk))
  model$pk    = c(0.1,0.5,0.4) # rdirichlet(1,rep(1,nk))
  model$nk    = nk
  return(model)
}


model.simulate <-function(model,N,sd.scale=1) {
  
  Y = array(0,sum(N)) 
  K  = array(0,sum(N)) 
  
  A   = model$A
  S   = model$S
  pk  = model$pk
  nk  = model$nk
  
  K = sample.int(nk,N,TRUE,pk)
  
  Y1  = A[K] + S[K] * rnorm(N) *sd.scale
  Y2  = A[K] + S[K] * rnorm(N) *sd.scale
  Y3  = A[K] + S[K] * rnorm(N) *sd.scale
  
  data.sim = data.table(y1=Y1,y2=Y2,y3=Y3)
  
  return(data.sim)  
}

N = 100000
nk = 3
ng = 2

set.seed(123432)

model = model.fun(nk)
model2 = model.fun(nk)
data = model.simulate(model, N/2)
data2 = model.simulate(model2, N/2)

data$g = 1
data2$g = 2

data = rbind(data, data2)

Y1 = data$y1
Y2 = data$y2
Y3 = data$y3
G = data$g


tau = array(0,c(N,nk))
lpm = array(0,c(N,nk))
lik0 = 1
lik = 0
pk = array(c(1/3,1/3,1/3),c(3,1))



A = array(rnorm(9, 5, 1), c(nk,ng))
S = array(abs(rnorm(9, 1, 10)), c(nk,ng))
tol = 1e-24
iter = 0
# tauold = 1


Xg = array(0, c(N, ng))
Xg[,1] = as.numeric(G ==1)
Xg[,2] = as.numeric(G ==2)



while (abs(lik-lik0)>tol) {
  lik0 = lik
  lik = 0
  
  ###### E-step #########
  
  ltau = array(1,N)%*%t(log(pk))
  lnorm1 = lognormpdf(Y1, t(A[,G]), t(S[,G]))
  lnorm2 = lognormpdf(Y2, t(A[,G]), t(S[,G]))
  lnorm3 = lognormpdf(Y3, t(A[,G]), t(S[,G]))
  lall = ltau +lnorm1 + lnorm2 +lnorm3
  lik = logsumexp(lall)
  
  
  # Q1 = sum(tau*lpm)
  # Q2 = sum(tau*lall)
  
  tau = exp(lall - logrowSumexp(lall))
  lpm = lall
  
  # H1 = -sum(tauold*log(tauold))
  # H2 = -sum(tauold*log(tau))
  # tauold = tau

  
  
  pk = colMeans(tau)
  
  
  ##### M-step ########
  
  
  # Solve for means by group
  
  A = t(tau* (Y1 %*% t(rep(1,nk))+Y2 %*% t(rep(1,nk))+Y3 %*% t(rep(1,nk)))) %*% Xg/(3*t(tau) %*% Xg)
  
  # Solve for standard deviations by group
  
  S = sqrt((t(tau* ((Y1 %*%t(rep(1,3))-t(A[,G]))^2+(Y2 %*%t(rep(1,3))-t(A[,G]))^2+(Y3 %*%t(rep(1,3))-t(A[,G]))^2)) %*% Xg)/(3*t(tau) %*% Xg))
  

  # print(c(iter, abs(lik-lik0), lik, Q2-Q1, H2-H1))
  print(c(iter, abs(lik-lik0), lik))
  iter = iter+1
}
```

Comment: $q_k = 1/k$ since you fix it before hand it it has to sum up to $1$. Then you take the Q function, compute partial derivatives, equal with 0, derive the equations for the two steps. This is what you ask?

Comment: I don't see why $q_k = 1/k$; the only constraints are that they need to sum up to 1 and $\{q_{kg}\}_g$ has to be independent of $g$.

Comment: It would be nice to see the complete model as an equation, since "groups" is not an usual term for mixtures. From reading the question, it seems the likelihood is a product of $G$ Normal mixture likelihoods, all sharing the same weights. If so, EM can be easily adapted to this setting.

Comment: @Xi'an: no, thanks for your responses! I think I tried to do the problem exactly as you mentioned before asking the question, but wasn't able to get the solution to converge. I now spent some time understanding the theory better. My true set-up is actually slightly more complicated, and I believe that's producing the problems, but I think I might now understand the problem. I will try to check, if I can fix it, and if everything works in the end.

Answer (score 1):

If the observed log-likelihood reads
$$\sum_{g=1}^G \sum_{i=1}^{N_g} \log \sum_{k=1}^K q_k \varphi(y_{ig};\mu_{gk},\sigma_{gk})$$
the completed log-likelihood reads
$$\sum_{g=1}^G \sum_{i=1}^{N_g} \sum_{k=1}^K z_{kig}\log \{q_k \varphi(y_{ig};\mu_{gk},\sigma_{gk})\}$$
where the $z_{kig}$'s are the component indicator variables. The E-function can thus be written as
\begin{align}Q(\theta_0,\theta)&=\mathbb E_{\theta_0}\left[\sum_{g=1}^G \sum_{i=1}^{N_g} \sum_{k=1}^K Z_{kig}\log \{q_k \varphi(y_{ig};\mu_{gk},\sigma_{gk})\} \big| \mathbf y\right]\\
&=\sum_{g=1}^G \sum_{i=1}^{N_g} \sum_{k=1}^K \mathbb E_{\theta_0}\left[Z_{kig}\big| \mathbf y\right]\log \{q_k \varphi(y_{ig};\mu_{gk},\sigma_{gk})\}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^K \log \{q_k\}\sum_{g=1}^G \sum_{i=1}^{N_g}\mathbb P_{\theta_0}\left[Z_{kig}=1\big| \mathbf y\right]\\
&\quad+\sum_{g=1}^G \sum_{i=1}^{N_g} \sum_{k=1}^K \mathbb P_{\theta_0}\left[Z_{kig}=1\big| \mathbf y\right]\log \{\varphi(y_{ig};\mu_{gk},\sigma_{gk})\}\\
\end{align}
which means that the update of the $q_k$'s in the EM algorithm is based on the expected allocations across groups. Nothing changes for the other group-specific parameters.

Comment: I tried to do this, but I probably misunderstood something, since I cannot seem to get it working. I edited my question with a reproducible code of my implementation. It first simulates a panel data of 3 observations for each individual along with an observable group (1 or 2). I then try to estimate the group specific parameters, but for some reason it doesn't seem to be working. It's possible I have a mistake somewhere in the code, but I wasn't able to spot it.

Comment: I ran the code and the only parameter that is poorly estimated is the mean vector.

Comment: But the performances vary with the `seed` value.

Comment: The mean vector is my main parameter of interest, so I would need to get it right. Is there any hope to fix it? Is there a reason, why EM doesn't work here (assuming I don't have a mistake in the code? 

I also noticed that the seed value affects the performance a lot, and for illustrative purposes, for this example I chose a seed, which estimates the parameters relatively fast. I think the problem is that if the true parameters are close to each other, the convergence is very slow and the estimates might be off even more.

Comment: It seems that the estimated parameters actually give higher likelihood than the true parameters used for the simulation. Is it possible that this is all just the bias of MLE? Increasing the sample size to 1,000,000 slightly improves the fit, but it's still quite far for the mean vector.