# How to isolate out groups from a sample

Tags: regression, missing-data, sample

Lets say you are doing a study on a group of people in which you record their weight over time and get an average chart of weight/time.

You suspect that this average chart is not really a good representation of any one individual because individuals fall under one of three categories whose averages have a distinct chart shape which is different from the overall average one.

However, you do not have a marker that can identify which person belongs to which category (only info is weight/time entry) AND you don't know what the average chart pattern for each category might look like, only the overall average.

Is it possible to discern the narrower group patterns of weight/time within the sample? What is the best approach to do so?

Comment: Maybe see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/518536/em-algorithm-for-normal-mixtures-with-constraints

Comment: Serach cluster analysis, (gaussian) mixture models, .... maybe see https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/0013164420925122